# KeyError: 'view_class' When trying to add a route using app.route and api.add_resource in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have this flask project that is using flask_restful for creating and API and that also includes server-side rendering.:

app.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from ma import ma

from blacklist import BLACKLIST

from resources.test import Test



from db import db


# Init app

app = Flask(__name__,
            static_folder='static',
            template_folder='templates',
            )

# Init Api
api = Api(app)
# Init db
db.init_app(app)
# Init ma
ma.init_app(app)
# Init migrate
migrate = Migrate(app, db)


@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return "Hello World"

api.add_resource(Test, "/api/test/<string:test_id>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP_RUN_HOST = os.environ.get("APP_RUN_HOST")
    app.run(APP_RUN_HOST, port=5000)
```

resources/test.py

```
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse

from models.test import TestModel
from schemas.test import TestSchema

test_schema = TestSchema()


class Test(Resource):
    @classmethod
    # @jwt_required()
    def get(cls, test_id: int):
        test = TestModel.find_by_id(test_id)
        if test:
            return test_schema.dump(test), 200
        return {"message": gettext("test_test_not_found")}, 404
```

I also have `schemas/test.py` and `models/test.py`

**Here is the problem:**
When I run python app.py I see this error:

```
line 423, in _register_view
    previous_view_class = app.view_functions[endpoint].__dict__['view_class']
KeyError: 'view_class'
```

---

Any fix or explanation for this problem? The error is telling me that a key is missing. And the application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question:

For each URL, there is an endpoint that is the name of that URL route.

**The difference between endpoint and URL in flask terminology:**

The "endpoint" is the name for a route. The endpoint name is the registration key for views, a symbolic name by which you can reference the route from other parts of your application.
Flask itself assumes the name of the view function as an endpoint.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    pass
```

is Equal to:

```
def index():
    pass
app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
```

To better understand it, and to see the url_map, this can be done:

change the directory where app.py is located. Then:

```
- > flask shell
- >>> from app import app
- >>> app.url_map
```

So the reason this has happened is that when I create the route

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return "Hello World"
```

an endpoint named test adds to the URL map:
`<Rule '/test' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> test>`

and when flask tries to create a `test` endpoint at this line

`api.add_resource(Test, "/api/test/<string:test_id>")`

it cannot do so because an endpoint with the same name is already used.
That is why

`/api/test/<string:test_id>`

is missing from the url_map.

**The solution for this problem is adding an endpoint name to the routes as below:**

```
@app.route('/test', endpoint='test')
def test():
    return "Hello World"

api.add_resource(Test, "/api/test/<string:test_id>", endpoint='test-api')
```